# How to convert and append days into hours of Period Class in java?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a method which determines the period between two dateTime variables.

```
Period period = new Period(startTime, endTime);
PeriodFormatter runDurationFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2).appendDays().appendSeparator(":").appendHours().appendSeparator(":").appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":").appendSeconds().toFormatter();
return runDurationFormatter.print(period);
```

I would expect to see 00:01:00 for 1 minute, 23:00:00 for 23 hours, 30:00:00 for 30 hours, and 120:00:00 for 120 hours (5 days).
I tried using

```
Period daystoHours = period.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.time());
```

But eclipse shows that normalizedStandard() method is undefined for type period.

Comment: The method [Period.normalizedStandard()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#normalizedStandard-org.joda.time.PeriodType-) exists since Joda-Time-version v1.5. Make sure that a) you don't use a stone-old version and b) use the right imports (see answer of @Gordeev)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you are using the Period class from `org.joda.time` package, not from `java.time`. Following example may help you.

```
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.PeriodType;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Launcher
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 4, 12, 0, 0, 0);
        Calendar end = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 4, 17, 0, 0, 0);

        Period period = new Period(start.getTimeInMillis(), end.getTimeInMillis());

        PeriodFormatter runDurationFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().printZeroAlways()
            .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
            .appendHours().appendSeparator(":")    // <-- say formatter to emit hours
            .appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":")  // <-- say formatter to emit minutes
            .appendSeconds()                       // <-- say formatter to emit seconds
            .toFormatter();

        // here we are expecting the following result string 120:00:00
        System.out.println(
            runDurationFormatter.print(period.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.time()))
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i am not able to use period.normalizedStandard(PeriodType.time()), it says normalizedStandard is undefined for type period.